# Simplest way to send encrypted List<MyObject> using WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

The Get method in my web service looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{companyId:Guid}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid companyId)
{
    var result = GetData(companyId); // returns List<MyObject>
    return Ok<IEnumerable<MyObject>>(result);
}
```

Here's how I receive in my client:

```
var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<MyObject>>().Result;
```

What is the simplest way to send the data encrypted without having to convert to a byte array, E.g.

- web service converts result to byte[]
- web service encrypts byte array
- client receives byte[]
- client decrypts byte array

Comment: The simplest way is to make the transfer using an encrypted channel, like over http**S**.

Comment: Well, isn't that fun, this question got closed just as I was about to post my answer.  It's as simple as decorating your method with the `[RequireHttps]` attribute, [see this article for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api).

Comment: See the answer with the highest vote count (not the accepted answer) in the marked duplicate.

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt it? Who are you protecting the data against/for?

Comment: Wow, the "duplicate question" isn't even about the same thing, it's playing with the stream directly rather, which this question is not.  It's a very poor example.

Comment: @igor, actually look at the question and answer you've linked to.  It's not a duplicate.

Comment: Judging by the way this question is written, in particular, the bottom part, I think it is a *very* good fit, however, I don't think the question is written specific enough to know if it's a perfect fit.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to use an SSL cert on your domain.  This would give you the https url that is encrypted and you wouldn't have to encrypt in your code.